# how to redirect to different domain based on complex subdomain conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do something somewhat complex with limited regex and htaccess understanding.

Say I have a domains like: (h removed so these dont get made into links)

ttp://feed.marker.sub.live.com

ttp://feed2.marker.sub.live.com

ttp://feed2.marker.live.com

If the word marker is in that domain AND there's a feedx subdomain preceding it, (feedx could be any word)

Then I want to rewrite it to

ttp://feed.marker.sub.dev.com

ttp://feed2.marker.sub.dev.com

ttp://feed2.marker.dev.com
(in that order)

But
ttp://marker.sub.live.com should not be rewritten nor should

ttp://anythingelse.live.com or

ttp://feed.anythingelse.live.com or

ttp://marker.live.com

Why? so in our peculiar environment, we can get feeds that will ultimately be tested on a live server worked on off the dev server til we're ready.

I'm looking for something in the realm of 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).marker.(.*).live.com
RewriteRule ,,,

Well, that's my question. I'll post any ideas if I think I'm closer to a solution.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^marker(\.sub)?.live.com$
RewriteRule / - [last]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+?\d?\.marker\.)(sub\.)?live\.com$
RewriteRule / http://%1%2dev.com [redirect,last]
```